# how often to upgrade packages during a full stack development?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, mean-stack

I'm a c++ developer, but lately start to work on the full stack development project. I've noticed that in a typical nodejs project, a lot third party libraries (or called packages in the Javascript community) are needed and not all of the packages are mature and constantly growing or even rewritten. Upgrading causes lots problems (e.g., angular ui directives have to be rewritten, some functions are removed and need to be replaced etc.) I'm just wondering what's the best practice regarding maintaining and upgrading packages during a typical full stack development? Once in a year or once in a week or once for all and only rewrite if needed?

Comment: In general, "what's the best practice" type questions are too opinionated to be answered effectively here.  Every answer provided could be the right answer, and the wrong answer at the same time.

Comment: For example (as a small attempt to address your question), Some applications require specific libraries to always be up to date, because of security concerns, user requirements, or other concerns.  Other applications only require an up to date version of libraries when they need a new feature only available in the new library.  Some applications only function because of libraries, others only use libraries as helpers.  Each situation would have a different take on what is important.

Comment: Specifically, here I'm more concerned about ui packages, e.g., bootstrap. The standards of using the library is always changing. The one-page application I'm working on was developed one and half year ago using angularjs 1.0 and bootstrap 0.11.2, but now angularjs is 2.0 and bootstrap is 2.3.2, not even talking about MEANJS stack version. For those ui packages, do you guys do constant updating (e.g., whenever there's a new version of ui package) or only update whenever it is required or needed (e.g., missing feature is only available in a new version).

Comment: I have this confusion just because in c++ world, the third party libraries are self-contained and interface changes are not that often. Just like windows os updates, we can easily manage updates on a regular basis or whenever needed. Though, in the web application, what I see is that interface changes are very often, managing updates often require a rewrite. I just want to get some idea about how you guys do in such a constant changing development environment.